# Remove HeatmapLayer from google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm using the HeatmapLayer api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps

I generate the heatmap like this:

```
heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatmapData,
    radius: 50
});
heatmap.setMap(google_map);
```

When i want to display another heat map using the same function as above (i'm using ajax and i have new markers to display, so i need to change the heatmap too) the heat map layer stays on the map and in this case i have 2 overlapping heatmaps on my map. How can i remove the current heatmaplayer first?

Here is my demo code, if you click on the link below the map, the heatmap is added, of you click on it again, it should remove it, but its just duplicated over and over again:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpL3P/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The docs suggest you can remove a layer by calling `heatmap.setMap(null)`

**Update**

In [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpL3P/) you were declaring your `heatmap` variable in the scope of each `click` event.  To make your code work I moved the `heatmap` variable to exist globally, and then checked to make sure that a new `heatmap` did not overwrite an existing one.

[Here is your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpL3P/1/)

Comment: Thanks, i updated my question with a demo, its not working properly

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else searching for a solution years after the original post I found the following worked.
Begin by declaring the variable as a global that will hold the heatmap MVCObject.

```
var mvcObj;
```

Then, in the function you use to add the heatmap

```
if( typeof( mvcObj )=='object' ) mvcObj.clear();
/* locations is an array of latlngs */
mvcObj = new google.maps.MVCArray( locations );

/* this.map is a reference to the map object */
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: mvcObj,
    map: this.map
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the `heatmap` globally and then when you want to display new data on the heatmap do this:

```
let heatmap;

setData(heatmapData) {
    if (heatmap) {
      // Clear heatmap data
      heatmap.setMap(null);
      heatmap.setData([]);
    }
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: heatmapData
    });

    heatmap.setMap(this.map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `heatmap.setMap(null)` will only hide your heatmap layer.
If you later type `heatmap.setMap(map)`, you will see your heatmap layer again, so it didn't really get deleted.

In order to delete the data you have to do the following steps.

`heatmap.setMap(null)` //This will hide the heatmap layer

`heatmap.getData().j = [];` //This is what actually sets the coordinates array to zero.

`heatmap.setMap(map)`  //Now when you toggle back the map, the heatlayer is gone and you can create a new one.

Hope this helps. Took me a while to figure it out, but it definitely worked.

Comment: Do not reference an internal property name like .j as Google regularly changes these reference letters in their minification system for new versions. Instead, do heatmap.setData([])

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation here [google JSHeatMaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps).

Check out this [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap). You can view the logic for the toggle button.

```
heatmap.setMap(null)
```

Comment: See my updated question with a sample code, its not working somehow