# Animated heatmap with new data sets

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I have created a simple heatmap (using google maps api v3), into which I would like to add an element of basic animation.

I have a number of collections of datapoints, each collection representing a time period (say 30 minutes).

I want to "replay" the heatmaps corresponding to one collection of data, followed by the next collection, and the next, and so on. Almost like replaying video frames.

I have tried doing this with an MVCArray, which I clear and update with the new datapoints. Something like this

```
data = new google.maps.MVCArray(datapoints);
```

then after a few seconds:

```
for (i=0;i<data.getLength();i++){
        data.removeAt(i);
    }
```

This does not work, because the new heatmap data will simply be added ontop of the old heatmap in the browser, even though the data array was succesfully cleared.

This problem, and a basic solution is described here:
[Remove HeatmapLayer from google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104547/remove-heatmaplayer-from-google-maps)

The solution is to clear the heatmap using:

```
heatmap.setMap(null)
```

However, this does not work for me, since this will completely clear the heatmap, and leave the map empty for a second or two. That is to say, the animation effect is lost.

Any suggestions out there on what I could do?

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) ?.

Comment: Sure! I simplified a bit, but it captures my problem. What the script does is to, first create a heatmap, and then wait 5 sek, and create another one.

http://jsfiddle.net/NNwx7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it's possible to really animate one heatmap into the other but it is definitely possible to do something like [this](http://www.look-out.info/demo/heatmap1/animated.html).

Which is basically doing the same thing you did, but at a quicker rate.

You can achieve something like that with some basic JavaScript.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // initialise variables
    var speed=5;
    x=0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){},10000000);
    var heatmap;

    // function to change map
    function changeSpeed(change) {
        speed = speed+change;
        if (speed<=0) speed=1;
        if (speed>=10) speed=10;

        // speed --> delay
        if (speed>5) {
            delay=1000/(speed-5);
        } else {
            delay=1000*(6-speed);
        }

        document.getElementById('speed').firstChild.nodeValue=speed;

        // restarting the function
        clearInterval(interval)
        interval=setInterval(function(){
                    x++;
                    if (x>=heatmapFiles.length) x=0;
                    // document.getElementById('filename').firstChild.nodeValue=heatmapFiles[x];

                    var re = /[0-9]{8}/;
                    var datestr = re.exec(heatmapFiles[x])[0];
                    document.getElementById('date').firstChild.nodeValue=datestr.substring(6,8)+"."+datestr.substring(4,6)+"."+datestr.substring(0,4);

                    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.open("GET", "./"+heatmapFiles[x], true);
                    req.onreadystatechange = function heatmapLoaded() {
                        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                            eval("map="+req.responseText);
                            heatmap.setData(map);
                        }
                    }
                    req.send(null); 

                    // redraw
                    document.getElementById('boxed').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('boxed').style.display = 'inline-block';

         },delay);

    }
  // this is important for you
  function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                                zoom: 2,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                });

      // creating a new heatmap
      heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ radius: 50 });
      heatmap.setMap(map);

      // calling the 'change map' function
      changeSpeed(0);
  }

    </script>
```

**How does it work?**

The heat map data are stored in JSON format in seperate Javascript files. A timer is used to load the next dataset. It will be parsed and assigned to the “data” property of the Google Maps HeatMapLayer object. After the property has been changed, the heatmap is redrawn automatically with the new data set. [source](http://look-out.info/2013/02/animated-heat-maps/)

**Alternatively**

You could create the different heatmaps in different `div`s and then use jQuery to `fadeIn` the 'new' heatmap and `fadeOut` the 'old' heatmap at the same time. This would create a sort of 'animation'.

I hope this helps you out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! This will work! (I just hope I can get it right... :-)