# Having issues clearing google maps layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've been working off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104547/remove-heatmaplayer-from-google-maps) and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpL3P/1/). I'm trying to clear the map layer before I populate new data into it, but it looks like overlays just stack one on top of one another without ever getting cleared.

Here's my code as it currently exists:

```
// For the heatmap layer
  var heatmapData = [];
  var heatmap;

  // Instantiate counter
  var files = 0;

  // Looping and loading files with timeout
  (function myLoop (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', ('js/tweets'+ files + '.json'), true);
      xhr.onload = function() {
        loadTweets(this.responseText);
      };
      xhr.send();

      // Clear out map styles
      heatmap.setMap(null);           
      if (--i) myLoop(i);
      // Stall for 3 seconds
    }, 3000)
  })(100);  

  // Parse out the JSON and create markers
  function loadTweets(results) {

    // Parse out our JSON file
    var tweetStructure = $.parseJSON(results);

    // Go gets it
    for (a in tweetStructure){
      var co_arr = tweetStructure[a];
      for (coords in co_arr.coordinates){
        var d = co_arr.coordinates;

        // Stating our lat/longs 
        var first = d[0];
        var second = d[1];
        var magnitude = d[2];

        // Setting them
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(first, second);

        // Weighted location to express polarity
        var weightedLoc = {
          location: latLng,
          weight: Math.pow(2, magnitude)
        };
        heatmapData.push(weightedLoc);
      }
    }

    // Instantiate heat map
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: heatmapData,
      dissipating: false,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

I'm getting my data from four static JSON files.

Comment: This post might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847944/toggle-between-data-in-google-heat-map

Answer (score 0):

With the second `for in` loop when declaring `var d =` you don't seem to be iterating though all `[coords]`. So as a result I guess `d[0]` will house all key-value pairs from `co_arr.coordinates`. Might this be part of the problem?